# Is there a name for smaller text on top of bigger text in typography or UI design?

Tags: terminology

I have a pattern where important clickable links have smaller text on top of big text to save horizontal space and emphasize the bigger text.

Example:

[image]

What do you call the smaller text? I'm just trying to name my CSS classes. I'm looking for something semantic like how HTML tags are designed that describes what it is, and not how it looks.

Comment: I'd call it a subheading

Comment: I've thought about that, but don't you need a heading for there to be a subheading? Otherwise the subheading is just a heading, and technically the big text of the link is not a heading since it does not describe a section of content, it is a self-contained link. Maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: You could call the whole thing a "banner"

Comment: Well in order to give you a semantic name for the text that comes before your link, might I ask what class you named the actual link?

Comment: Nothing right now, other than the fact that it's an anchor tag. It's literally just a link that looks like the picture above, and I'm stumped on the naming. To clarify, the small text is contained in the link, it's not before the link.

Comment: I'm already using the "banner" class, unfortunately.

Comment: You could use something like primary, secondary, tertiary, quaternary, quinary etc.

Comment: I think this question is way too open-ended and really a matter of personal preference.  After all, CSS classes allow you to pretty much call anything whatever you want.  That being said, I would probably just call them "preheading" or "superheading"...something like that.

Comment: I could show you a picture of a ui carousel or a ui button and ask "what is this called?", does that make it an open-ended question? What I'm essentially asking is, "is there a common name for this pattern?" and if the answer is "no", then the answer is "no". That doesn't make the question open-ended.

Answer (score -1):

you could use a span tag within the banner class, and call it small or smalltext.

Comment: Hi Ana, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer. I'm sorry, I don't see how your input answers the Asker's question. They indicate they want to know what a somewhat official name is, 'desrcib[ing] what it is, and not how it looks'. If you have any questions about this site, have a look at the [help] or feel free to ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks Vincent, unlike headings, there is not an official name for classes. I was suggesting a way to facilitate the organization of the Asker's stylesheet by using a span class instead and referring to the description of the class itself when naming these. In this case would be 'smalltext' inside the 'banner' class, hope it makes sense